# Github still asking for credentials despite successful creation of deploy key?

Tags: github, deploy-keys

I have created a deploy key according to the windows instructions [here](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.16/user/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)

But instead of using the deploy key that has just been set up, `git push` instead asks for credentials, first with a pop up, then with an SSH pop up, then in the git bash command line itself! This is quite shocking because the whole purpose of a deploy key is to avoid having to provide access to an entire github account

Given I have followed github's own instructions precisely and this isn't working, I am lost as to what to do next.

#### Notes

- Some time ago, somehow, I set up a deploy key successfully on the same (windows) server. So perhaps the > 1 key on the machine is confusing some part of the process. I am not sure this has anything to do with it though.
- I can see [here](https://gist.github.com/adamjohnson/5682757) that github expects keys to be named `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`, but given this is my *second* deploy key running on this particular server, I named the second set differently so as to avoid overwriting the original set (the original set are still there, there are just two more files in `C:\Users\[YOUR-USER-NAME]\.ssh\`)

Comment: Is your remote SSH or HTTPS?  You can check with `git remote -v`.

Comment: @bk2204 great idea. I checked and it returned the HTTP remote. So I updated the remote to SSH and now `git remote -v` returns `origin  git@github.com:stevecondylios/cran-libraries.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:stevecondylios/cran-libraries.git (push)`

Comment: @bk2204 I now see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58416318/how-to-push-to-github-using-deploy-key-on-windows) error message when I try to `git push`

Comment: @bk2204 I have found some related info [here](https://gist.github.com/adamjohnson/5682757) but am still not exactly sure what to try, and also do not want to accidentally break the original (working) deploy key

Comment: After a LOT of googling, I got it sorted. Github user 'NickWoodham' comment [here](https://gist.github.com/jamesmcfadden/d379e04e7ae2861414886af189ec59e5) is what I used - seems to work well